# How to show how many people wants a product in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
$query2 = "SELECT reverse_products.id, reverse_products.name, reverse_relations.user_id
FROM reverse_products JOIN reverse_relations ON reverse_products.id = reverse_relations.product_id
WHERE product_id = $dealid ";

$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query2));

echo "$row[id]: $row[name]";
```

that shows the *id* and *name* of a product from `reverse_products` table. On the `reverse_relations` table there are stored *user_id* and *product_id*. There are many *user_id* that may have the same *product_id*.

How to change my query to show :
On how many *user_id* have the same *product_id* ? Do I need a second query for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(user_id)
FROM reverse_relations
GROUP BY product_id
WHERE product_id = $dealid
```

if I'm understanding your table structure properly.

Comment: I really need a second query for this ? (going with sql way)

Comment: If you want the count from a query, yes. You'd have to use a group-by clause since it's using an aggregate function and fetching non-aggregate results as well, and this'd destroy the individual rows

Answer (score 0):

```
count(reverse_relations.user_id) as num
echo $row[num]
```